Using Spring Boot and Flyaway Migrations, but it isn't putting schema in the correct PostgreSQL database
I have the respective configuration etc, for flyway and the Spring app in the application settings. Then in the first migration I have the following:
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "the_system";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "the_collections";

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

It seems to run fine, but it keeps sticking these schema in the postgres database vs. the database I created called "ctt". Is there a particular place or location where I need to tell the Spring Boot Flyway migrations to use a particular database.
To which, my connection string does indeed have the database in the connection string, so I should be connected to it by every measure.
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ctt

Thoughts?
